# How to set the constraint in a table to avoid two records have the same values in every column but the identity column are different?

Tags: database, constraints

I set up an identity column to a table to make it automatically insert the ID for each record inserted. But it made the table keep two same records(except the identity column) in a table. Are there any ways that I can set up some constraint to compare the value of each column for each record to avoid this happen. For example , those two records in the read circle are the same except identity column 'ID', I want to set up a constraint to avoid the second record (ID:29) to be inserted.

Thanks

[pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YA7NE4EzN0hHb8M9d2rnOVXHzbao1KEt)

Answer (score 0):

When you use an identity column as the primary key in a relation you are saying "The value in the identity column is what makes this row unique."

You could use one or more check clauses to handle the risk of duplication but the best way to avoid duplicate rows is to use natural keys.